# ASP MVC5 - Identity. How to get current ApplicationUser and use this user to query a table with user as foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC application. I used Individual User Accounts and Identity API in such a way that only those users in the canEdit role will be able to edit data (my data are products). ASPNetUsers and Products entities have a 1:N relations (it's only an example). So a user has (owns) a list of products.

When a user requests `http://localhost:1111/Products` the page should show the list of products of that user that previously logged in.

I'm not sure how to get current ApplicationUser and how to query the products table to get the list of products that belong to an user.

This is the code of my ProductsController:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();


    // GET: Products
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);

        //How to modify these sentence to get the products of the current user??
        Product product = db.Products.Find();
        return View(db.Products.ToList());
    }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using Individual Authentication you should be able to access the user directly from the Application DB using the users ID:

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
```

This will create an object with users from your database, then you can simply call it using something like:

```
CurrentUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

To get the currently logged in user, the `User` object should be populated with details of the logged in user automatically.

As you have the `[AllowAnonymous]` Attribute you will also have to make sure the user is actually logged in using `Request.IsAuthenticated` otherwise the User object will be null.

Adding it all together will make your code look something like:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
        ApplicationUser currentUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        // assuming there is some kind of relationship between products and users
        List<Product> products = db.Products.Where(p => p.User.Equals(currentUser.UserID)).ToList(); // or .email or other field from your users table

        // OPTIONAL: Make sure they see something
        if(products.Count ==0) // They have no related products so just send all of them
            products = db.Products.ToList();

        // only send the products related to that user
        return View(products);
    }
    // User is not authenticated, send them all products
    return View(db.Products.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you have the UserId in the Products class, if yes, then:

```
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

var userProducts=db.products.Where(p=>p.UserId==currentUserId).Tolist();

//you need to replace in my code the UserId with the name of the user id from your products table.
```

istead of `return View(db.Products.ToList());` you just need to write `return View(userProducts);`

...and like Jake said: remove the attribute `[AllowAnonymous]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Product product = CurrentUser.Products;
```